# How to give submit button outside form its form property when form's id property is dynamic in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, forms

I have some dynamic tabs in Angular. Each of the tabs contains a dynamic form.
I noticed that Angular doesn't encapsulate form id property, and because of this id need to be set dynamically, so each tab has separate form id:

```
<form id="tab{{itemId}}"
  [formGroup]="FormTab"
  (ngSubmit)="save()">
</form>
```

Because the structure of each tab is complex, fields and buttons (including submit button in question) are not inside the `<form>` tag itself. I am using HTML `form` property to point form's id.

Somewhere in each tab there is a button:

```
<button form="tab{{itemId}}"
        type="submit"></button>
```

Normally, when it would be static `<button form="tabStatic" type="submit"></button>` - the `form` property would work and act as submit button for form `<form id="tabStatic">` but apparently Angular doesn't support binding or interpolation in HTML property `form`. Or am I wrong?

How do I approach this? How to set button's form property with dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working for me:

```
<form id="tab{{itemId}}" [formGroup]="FormTab" (ngSubmit)="save()" 
  #refForm="ngForm">

</form>

<input type="button" form="tab{{itemId}}" value="Save" 
    (click)="refForm.ngSubmit.emit()" />
```

Thanks!